# Kill command in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, virtual-machine

I've a batch with following command to kill an exe.
taskkill /IM MyTest.exe

Am running this batch file on a VM machine(Windows Server 2003) where MyTest.exe could be running in 2 different sessions.
When I run the batch file on this machine,batch is able to kill MyTest.exe only in the session in which am logged in.
But I want the batch file to kill MyTest.exe running in the other session too.
If this is possible, how do I achieve it please?
(Both sessions are logged in with the same user account.)

Thanks.

Comment: Are the sessions logged into with the same user accounts?

Comment: Are they in two VMs?  You can't be logged in twice on a system with the same user account, can you?

Comment: OK virtual machines are generally septate. As if they are in a different box (septate) so they cant do any damage to the real OS so there may be some bypassing needed.

Comment: If they are separate virtual machines, you can only communicate from one to the other using a network connection or some shared disc resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
:A

echo off

taskkill /IM MyTest.exe || echo Done & goto :EOF

goto A
```